# cannot start your application.The work group information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user

Tags: report, oledb, provider, oledbconnection, jet

From OLE DB provider connection string have Username and Password. I am not able to use this Password.

If i choose mdf file from my system location and then given my server username and Password.It throws the error for -

```
cannot start your application.The work group information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.
```

But I should use Admin user and without Password its working. How to give my server username and Password for `*Microsof Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider*`

Answer (score -1):

To fix the issue this is what we did

Change your connection as Fellows:

string conString =@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="Path to your access file";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";

We removed the User id

Hope this helps someone